# Using distinct and order by in subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get distinct 'productnumber' ordered by the 'createdate' but at the end I need only "productnumber" sorted by 'createdate' (I cannot use top as the 'productnumber' varies in a wide flexible range).

The distinct product number is needed to be concatenated with comma (,) for e.g.
 123,245,787,875 (each number represents a productnumber)

The required query looks like somewhat (this query doesn't work and gives an error The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified):

```
SELECT stuff(
(
 SELECT distinct ',' + productnumber
 FROM Product
 ORDER BY createdate
 FOR XML path('')
)), 1, 1, '')
```

Could anyone help in how to go about to get the desired result.

Comment: What `createdate` should you order by if you have different values for `createdate` for duplicate values of `productnumber`?

Comment: Good Catch! You may assume there are multiple entries for the same Productnumber.I am more concerned of the correct way to do this.

Comment: One way would be to do a group by on productnumber and order by min(createdate). But only you can tell if that is what you want.

Comment: Hey Thanks Mikael.. it worked  i used group in place of distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson) suggested, using Group By clause solved the problem. Thanks Mikael

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT stuff((SELECT     ',' + productnumber
     FROM product a
     ORDER BY a.createdate FOR xml path('')),1,1,'')
     AS destn_str
```

Comment: I missed the brace while putting the query here. It does not work.

Comment: This might answer the question, but it would help if you tried explaining your answer. As it stands right now, this post is in the low quality queue.